# WSO2 EMM Android Configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I am facing problems while connecting with the emm store from my device.

I want to know what changes I have to make so that I can access emm store and can download the apps on my device. Any help will really be appreciated. I am not able to understand [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Android+Configurations)

Comment: Make sure that you have store related permissions assigned to you.

Comment: i am facing problems in android config as written in the documentation.could you please elaborate on how to properly configure this.

Comment: No additional android related configurations are required to login and subscribe applications to the devices. Can you provide the steps taken and where you need assistance?. Allow store related permissions to the user in order to login to the store.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to perform any android configurations for the emm server in order to enroll android devices. EMM server contains configurations for android.

> In the documentation you are provided with instructions how to modify
>   the agent app to use https protocol rather than http protocol and
>   generate a new .apk file.

**In order to connect your login to store and install applications to your device you need to provide related permissions to the related user. Use the carbon console for grant permissions**